# Where am I going wrong in my answer to creating histogram of number of words in the sentence? The code works only for 6 or less words

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, heap-memory

Question updated

Where am I going wrong in this code to create vertical histogram for number of letters in each word in a sentence? The code gives wrong output when i give this standard input
`we are going to write a really big sentence just to make sure I am not confused and writing it right`.

Anything big and I get an erroneous output.

I try to use heap(by using malloc and realloc) as I want to write a big sentence without worrying about limits. I know the source of problem is memory allocation but i don't understand the exact problem. Getting me a link to the solution available here would also be awesome.(please do suggest what I need to do if there is duplication of question as I am newbie here)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAXLETTERLENGTH 30
int main()
{
    int i,j,c,*nc,nw=0;
    nc=(int *)malloc(sizeof(nw));
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
    {   
        if(c==' ' || c=='\t')
        {
            ++nw;
            nc = realloc(nc, (nw + 1) * sizeof(*nc)); /*The updated improvement based on M.M's suggestion*/
        }
        else if(c=='\r' || c=='\n')
            break;
        else if(c=='\b')
            nc[nw]--;
        else if((c>='0' && c<='9') || (c>='A' && c<='Z') || (c>='a' && c<='z'))
            nc[nw]++;
    }
/*while(nw>=0)
{
    for(i=nc[nw];i>0;i-- && printf("%d|   |\n",nc[nw]))
        for(j=0;j<nw;printf("      ") && j++);
    nw--;
}*/
    for(i=MAXLETTERLENGTH;i>=1;--i)
    {
        for(j=0;j<=nw;j++)
        {
            if(i<=nc[j])
                putchar('*');
            else
                putchar(' ');
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    free(nc);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You go out of bounds of your array. You only ever realloc it to be 4 bytes big in total, but even as soon as `nw` hits to `1`, then `nc[nw]` will be off the end. You probably want `nc = realloc(nc, (nw + 1) * sizeof *nc);`

Comment: @M.M Thank you for the inputs. Much appreciated

Comment: Your program ignores its command line arguments; it is written as `int main()` rather than `int main(int argc, char **argv)` or equivalent which would allow you to access the command line arguments.  Since you're reading from standard input, you probably don't mean 'command line arguments'.

Comment: You need to think about your algorithms carefully.  What do you need to do?  You need to recognize each word as it comes, and be able to count how many characters are in it.  You need some sort of array for storing the count of the numbers of words with N characters in them for some suitable upper limit on the number of characters in a single word (32, 64, 128, 256 — none of those will strain the average computer on which you're doing this exercise).  When you reach EOF, you've got your set of counts; now you need to write a function to display the graph.  You'll have to decide how to do that.

Comment: Unless your course instructions say you must use `malloc()` etc, I would not expect your code to need to do so.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler Thank you for the inputs. I just ran off exporing things. Thanks again for your time! I will check up and be careful in implementations